# Can't open C:\Windows\System32\config folder from File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, administrator, jenkins

I just installed Jenkins 2.289.1 on Windows 10 Home. After Jenkins has started on browser, I have to go into `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword` to copy the password and continue the Jenkins set up.

I copied this path and pasted it to File Explorer and this message appeared:

```
Windows can't find
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
Check the spelling and try again.
```

On File Explorer I also tried to click on `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config` folder but nothing happens, so I tried to access it via CMD as Administrator and it works, but when I execute `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\start .` nothing shows up.

How can I resolve it?

P.S: I am the only user on PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I gather, Jenkins supposedly creates this file on the first start.

You cannot access this folder because both `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config` as well as `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile` are by default not accessible to normal users, for good reason.

Windows Explorer does by default not run elevated either.

If you manually navigate to the folder, you’ll get the following dialog two times. **I recommend you do not confirm it.** Doing so will grant your user permanent full access to critical system data. You don’t want that.

[image: grant folder access dialog]

Again: Don’t.

Instead, you should use an elevated process to access the file. This is easy with both Command Prompt as well as PowerShell:

```
type C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
```

If you want to use GUI tools to access the file, start Notepad (or whatever your favorite text editor is) elevated. You’ll then be able to open the file from the editor’s Open dialog.

Comment: Daniel B I authorized Jenkins to install as admin when the UAC dialog asked to me to complete the installation. `initialAdminPassword` is simple txt file in which Jenkins write a random password to use to finish the initial set up. I can access this file via CMD but I want to know why I can't open it via File Explorer

Comment: @Wuagliono I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Daniel B you got the point ! I was able to read `initialAdminPassword.txt` accessing it via CMD as admin. Now I have restarted my PC ( 1° first rule of IT : -)  ) and ONLY NOW when I try to click on `config` folder, appears the same dialog as yours. Following your advice, I  tried to use `Notepad` as admin and browse to `initialAdminPassword.txt` and open it.... IT WORKS ! Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't run `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\start .` because there isn't `start.exe` (or `start` with any extensions in `%PATHEXT%`) inside `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config`

To open the current folder you need to run `start .` or `explorer .`. If you want to open it from any folder then use `start C:\WINDOWS\system32\config` or `explorer C:\WINDOWS\system32\config`

But you don't need to open with administrative. Just explore `C:\WINDOWS\system32` then double click on the `config` folder. Explorer will say that you don't have permission to open that and ask for permission, just click yes and now you'll be inside

Comment: phuclv if I run `start C:\WINDOWS\system32\config`  on CMD still nothing happens. If I try to run  `start .` on any folder, it works and opens the folder on File Explorer. The strange thing is when I try to click on  `config` folder in the "tradional way", nothing happens !!! Windows doesn't show me anything, not even the permission to proceed as admin

Comment: @Wuagliono try running `explorer` in cmd with admin to run Explorer with admin rights and see. Or run `type C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword` in that cmd to see

Comment: @phulcv still nothing..... It's so strange..... Using `type C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword` CMD prompts  `The system cannot find the file specified.` but the file actually exists. I was able to read `initialAdminPassword.txt` opening CMD as admin and navigate through folders and then run `notepad initialAdminPassword.txt ` it will appears. Very strange.....

Comment: @Wuagliono that means you don't have permission to read the folder as I said, only admins have so you must run explorer.exe with admin rights